# PHP/Codeigniter Dry Principle on Model functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let's say i'm making a web application for a online story sharing site.

We have tables: genre,tags,content_warning with only 2 columns as id and name. for example: genre = 1 - romance, 2 - action, etc.

*I use the above tables to control/define each genre/tags/contentwarnings. so whenever a user publishes/uploads their own story they just cant input random tags/genre/contentwarnings.*

So i'll have these functions in my **story_model**:

```
public function get_genre(){
$genre = array();
$query = $this->db->get('genre');
foreach($query->result() as $row){
$genre[$row->genre_id] = $row->genre_name;
}
return $genre;
}

public function get_tags(){
$tags = array();
$query = $this->db->get('tag');
foreach($query->result() as $row){
$tags[$row->tag_id] = $row->tag_name;
}
return $tags;
}

public function get_content_warnings(){
$content_warning = array();
$query = $this->db->get('content_warning');
foreach($query->result() as $row){
$content_warnings[$row->content_warning_id] = $row->content_warning_name;
}
return $content_warning;
}
```

Am i correct to say that i am repeating myself in the above 3 functions? so i would write a single code like:

```
public function sample_get($table){
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->get($table);
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
            $data[$row[$table.'_id']] = $row[$table.'_name'];
        }
    return $data;
}
```

*to access the above function in my controller i would pass 'genre' or 'tag' or 'content_warning' as the parameter.*

How would i name my above function then? the 3 separate functions are easy to name as they are very direct to the point and you know what the function does by reading its name.

combining all 3 function into one makes it harder to name the function in a direct way. I like to name my function as direct as possible so its easy for me to follow. as in they're more readable.

Account_model:

```
public function get_userid($username){
$this->db->select('user_id');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->where('username', $username);
$query = $this->db->get();

foreach($query->result() as $row){
$user_id = $row->user_id;
}
return $user_id;
}
```

story_model:

```
public function get_stories($user_id){
$stories = array();

$this->db->select('story_id, story_name');
$this->db->from('story');
$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);//author
$query = $this->db->get();

foreach($query->result() as $row){
$stories[$row->story_id] = $row->story_name;
}

return $stories;
}
```

would the above two function warrant a dry-ification?

Or let's change the second function to only get the story_id which would coincide with the account_model function to get user_id. would they then be needed to dry?

but i get confused as to when do i decide to dry my functions? since i'll use alot of get function to retrieve data should i then just opt for a single get function?

Comment: Why not use the existing functions and let them call your internal, private method that contains the shared code?

Comment: I'm a beginner so  i hardly understood what you meant. can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your common, abstract function, but keep well-named public functions, you can take the following approach:

```
/**
  * Use the common function internally, but do not expose it publicly
  */
private function sample_get($table){
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->get($table);
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
            $data[$row[$table.'_id']] = $row[$table.'_name'];
        }
    return $data;
}

/**
  * Use well-named functions that are exposed to be used publicly
  */
public function get_content_warnings(){
    return $this->sample_get('content_warning');
}
```

This makes it possible to structure your class internally (through using the keyword `private`), but maintain a good interface to be used by other classes (through using `public`).

Comment: I assume both function exists in the same controller right?

so it's calling a function inside the same controller.

Comment: Yes, both functions exist in the same **model**

Comment: I have a question: I would still be making 3 public functions calling upon a single private function. aren't i simply repeating myself 3 times still hence needing to dry?

Comment: From my point of view, having a well-named interface to your class is more important than DRY, and as you use these three public functions that are as generalized as possible, this is no obvious case of DRY

Comment: For now i'll just stick to writing code then i'll worry about dry later. 

I might need to read up more on the topic, i just skimmed a few blogs about it, i might end up worsening my code, for now as long as its readable/easy to follow then its a good first step.